# Justification of kNN: sample mean vs expectation a binary variable?

Tags: mean, expected-value, binary-data, k-nearest-neighbour

Suppose, x is a random binary variable with values {0, 1},  and $E[x] > 0.5.$ Is it true that, for a random sample $S$ of $x$,   $P[\mu_S(x) > 0.5] > 0.5.$  In other words, if expectation of a binary variable is above 0.5, then mean of a random sample is more likely to be above 0.5 too. Is it true?

This is a justification of kNN. We take sample mean, round it, and output it as an answer for a given point. If sample mean is not representative of the expectation, then what is the point of kNN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your random sample consist of $n$ independent $X_i$'s, then sum of them $s(x)=\sum X_i$ is binomial with parameters $(n,p=E[X])$, and $P(\mu_s(x)>0.5)=P(s(x)>0.5n)$.

Here, let $n=4,p=0.51$, then $P(s(x)>2)\approx 0.328 <0.5$. So, although it is intuitive, it's not correct for all $n,E[X]$.

Comment: Probability that binomial random variable $s(x)$ satisfies $0.5 < s(x)  \le 1$ is defined by  cumulative binomial distribution. I have proof of my statement for odd numbers $n$.

Comment: Yes, I checked your example. It is correct. So, the general statement is wrong! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I proved the fact for samples of the size $k \ge 3$, where $k$ is an odd number.
It seems a rather general result, so, I wondered if somebody figured it out already.